# reveal_type gives me a type, but it does not exist

Tags: python, python-import, mypy, python-typing

So, I have a code that typechecks, but when I try to run it, it complains about the type not existing

```
import pyrsistent
a = pyrsistent.pset([1,2,3]) 
#reveal_type(a) #mypy file.py, gives type pyrsistent.typing.PSet[buildins.int]

#b : pyrsistent.typing.PSet[int] = a 
#when running: AttributeError: module 'pyrsistent' has no attribute 'typing'
#mypy does not complain, though

print ( a )
```

The line that fails is the assignment to the variable b (commented above)

How can I import the type, or anotate the code differently, to fix this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `import pyrsistent.typing` to get access to that submodule:

```py
import pyrsistent
import pyrsistent.typing

# To avoid the need to comment this call out; this will also print runtime type
from typing_extensions import reveal_type

a = pyrsistent.pset([1,2,3]) 
reveal_type(a) # N: revealed type is "pyrsistent.typing.PSet[builtins.int]"

b: pyrsistent.typing.PSet[int] = a 

print(a)
```

That's usual thing to do with nested modules: you cannot just access them as attributes before import if they are not explicitly added in root `__init__.py` of package.

`mypy` does not track this (not marking missing import/undefined symbol), because it's too difficult to say whether any of your imported packages (including *any* other module you imported that could do `import pyrsistent.typing` - it can happen in any namespace, even without explicit import later) has already imported it. For example, the following:

```py
# a.py
import pyrsistent.typing

# b.py
import pyrsistent
import a

pyrsistent.typing
```

will succeed, despite missing import on the first glance.

Comment: thanks! That was exactly what I needed (the answer and the context)